# java covariant return type

Tags: java, return, covariant

Why does below code prints "1" ?

```
class A {
    int x = 1;
}

class B extends A {
    int x = 2;
}

class Base {

    A getObject() {
        System.out.println("Base");
        return new B();
    }
}

public class CovariantReturn extends Base {

B getObject() {
   System.out.println("CovariantReturn");
   return new B(); 
}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Base test = new CovariantReturn();
    System.out.println(test.getObject() instanceof B);
    System.out.println(test.getObject().x);
}
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Because you are referring to fields, which are not affected by polymorphism. If you instead used `getX()`, it would've returned `2`.

What you are asking is, the value of field `x` defined in class `A` (because `Base.getObject()` returns `A`). Even though `CovariantReturn` overrides the method to return `B`, you are not referring to your object as `CovariantReturn`.

To expand a bit on how fields are not affected by polymorphism - field access is realized at compile time, so whatever the compiler sees, that's what's accessed. In your case the method defines to return `A` and so `A.x` is accessed. On the other hands methods are invoked based on the runtime type. So even if you define to return `A` but return an instance of `B`, the method you invoke will be invoked on `B`.

Comment: but the method defines to return `A`. And so `A.x` is what is accessed.

Comment: @kris you are calling method using reference of `A` in that it has thereturn type `A`

Comment: ok, so even though test.getObject() returns an instance of B, test variable is still Base reference therefore in case where I am printing x it calls Base:getObject() ?

Comment: test.getObject() instanceof B  returns true - that is what confuses me!

Comment: because the `instanceof` check happens at runtime. The `A.x` is realized at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

@kris979 Though you are returning B, i think what makes the difference is that the return type is of A. Hence value of x in A i.e. 1 is printed.

Answer (score 0):

As Bozho pointed out - instance variable are never affected by polymorphism. Let me give you a quick small example.

```
class Base {
    int i = 1;
    void method() {
        System.out.println("in base");
    }
}

class Sub extends Base {
    int i = 2;

    void method() {
        System.out.println("in sub");
    }
}

public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base obj = new Sub();
        obj.method();
        System.out.println(obj.i);
    }
}
```

This code will print - **in sub and 1**

Comment: nice. simple and neat answer